# AWS EC2 login issue

Tags: amazon-ec2

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to 54.85.116.155 [54.85.116.155] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file c:/Users/kirshna/Downloads/k3.pem type -1
debug1: identity file c:/Users/kirshna/Downloads/k3.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a4:cd:40:19:f7:8d:e2:b7:c8:1f:ce:4f:34:50:0b:23
debug1: Host '54.85.116.155' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kirshna/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kirshna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kirshna/.ssh/id_rsa_724
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kirshna/.ssh/id_rsa_ordital
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: c:/Users/kirshna/Downloads/k3.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: what was your connect command?

Comment: ssh  -v -i my.pem ubuntu@54.84.209.156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Putty, try using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and when you set it up install the openssh client.

Putty has a different way of specifying Private keys. (You need to import them into puttygen)

Comment: I am using ubuntu as its ubuntu machine.

Comment: Your logs don't say you are trying to login with `my.pem` they say you are trying to login with a `c:/Users/kirshna/Downloads/k3.pem`  . What ssh client are you using ?

Comment: I am using putty in windows.

Comment: What I am doing created ppk files using puttygen and imported with puttyy then its closing connection..

Comment: same issue with cygwin.. dont know how to fix this..can we jump to Skype please

Comment: I am stuck with this. I created a snapshot and launch new instance still the same issue

Comment: What's the original AMI that you are using?

Comment: What it mean? See I had the login issue and then I created a snapshot and launched new instance and problem still there.

Comment: Show I share aws login details with you? it will be really great help at this time. Our site went down and bussines impacted a lot

Comment: Ubuntu May not be the user that you are supposed to login as

Comment: I tried with all possisble users...dnt know where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear if you want help logging in using putty on Windows or you are logging in from terminal in Ubuntu.
If you are using Putty, then you need to convert the .pem to .ppk. You need puttygen for this.
Puttygen will take your .pem as input and create .ppk as output.

Next, you open putty and click on Connection->SSH->Auth.
Click on browse and select the .ppk file that contains your key in a putty-readable format.

Going to Session, entering ubuntu@your-ip-addess and hitting ENTER should do the trick.

I would post screenshot but I do not have enough reputation to do so.